# SSRS Expressions issue with separate datascope

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

```
DATEDIFF("d", First(Fields!CurrentEffDate.Value, "dstvwGMDEntryDetails"), Now())
```

have this as an expression it works perfectly 
but before it does this i need

```
Fields!IsTempProduct.Value, "dstvwProductDetails")=1
```

this if a product is a temporary product then show "BLANK"
else run

```
  DATEDIFF("d", First(Fields!CurrentEffDate.Value, "dstvwGMDEntryDetails"), Now())
```

i have tried this

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!IsTempProduct.Value, "dstvwProductDetails")=1,"",DATEDIFF("d", First(Fields!CurrentEffDate.Value, "dstvwGMDEntryDetails"), Now())
```

but its moaning about them being in a separate datascope and its summing temp product temp product is like a flag so for normal products temp product =0 temp =1

Comment: Where are you trying to put the expression, how are the different datasets? A little more information on the data and requirement would help us indeed.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at end of your `iif`.

Comment: Your expression should be `=IIF(Sum(Fields!IsTempProduct.Value, "dstvwProductDetails")=1,
"",
DATEDIFF("d", First(Fields!CurrentEffDate.Value, "dstvwGMDEntryDetails"), Now()))`